# What is the remainder when 1!+2!+3!+4!+5!+.......+50! is divided by 5!?

Tags: number-theory

> What is the remainder when 1!+2!+3!+4!+5!+.......+50! is divided by 5!

**My Approach**

$1$+$2$+$6$+$24$+$5$!/$5$!+$6 . 5$!/$5$!+$7$ .$6$ . $5$!/$5$!....so on

$33$+$1$+$6$+$42$+......

I am not getting the correct answer as the solution is getting complex.

Can anyone guide me how to approach the problem?

Comment: You asked almost the same question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1509183/find-the-remainder-when-123-49-is-divided-by-7?rq=1)...Using the same tools leads to a very similar solution...

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Terms of $5!$ onwards are divisble by $5!$, so you only need the remainer of $1! +2!+3!+4!$.

Comment: Okay I haven't thought of remainder After 5! all remainder will be 0.

Comment: @justintakro if this answer helps you please accept the answer by clicking on saffron button

Answer (score 0):

As Lee said $5!$ onwards all are divisible by $5!$  so we need remainder of($1!+2!+3!+4!$) 33 so remainder is 33.

Comment: Isn't the remainder when 33 is divided by 5! 33 itself?

Comment: The 5! Is over all the summatjon sk we can split 33 as 30+3

Comment: @ArchisWelankar: Would you care to repeat that comment in plain English? FYI $5!=120$.

Comment: Cant you write $33=6.5+3$ thats what i want to say let the sum be x .so $x+30+3$  whats the remainder??. Hope now you are clear on that.

Comment: @ArchisWelanker. Yes, 3 is the remainder when dividing by 5, but the question is what's the remainder when dividing by 120. So 33.